# What is the .hinc Extension on a file?

Tags: html, filenames, frontend

I'm working with some pre-existing web files for a website, and I see there are files with .hinc ending. The code inside them is HTML, but Sublime Text 2 doesn't seem to recognize it, and doesn't color anything. Also, the code still runs on the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.hinc is    an included HTML source file in c++. See this link http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3325.html#style.hinc